# Neural Stimulation-Generate spike trains from Biphasic pulse as an input

Tags: python, simulation, pulse, spike

I want to make a neural stimulation where the input is biphasic pulse and the output it spike trains. Does anyone have an idea how to generate the spike trains from biphasic pulse as an input. Thanks.

Comment: it's about Neural Computation ?

Comment: Yes, it's right!